# jQuery Validation Phone Number Prefix Only 3 Number (059)

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery validation method, I wish to make it to check the the prefix. I tried doing it but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Conditions:-

Must be starting 059
Example: 059XXXXXXX

Must be equal to 10 characters
Only numbers, no alphabets or other characters
This is what I have done

````
var pattern = /^0(59)[0-9]{8}$;  
if(!jQuery('#input_1_4').val()!= pattern ){
    alert('Error');
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is missing the closing slash, the quantifier should be 7 not 8, also you don't need the brackets and you are not using it correctly. The RegExp object has a [`.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) that can be utilized in such cases. Here is a working example:

```
var pattern = /^059[0-9]{7}$/;

if( !pattern.test(jQuery('#input_1_4').val()) ){
    alert('Error');
}
```

Comment: This would match 11 numbers, not 10

Answer (score 0):

You check if sting starts with `059` by using `^` operator. To ensure it contains numbers only, use `\d`. Finally to ensure length 10, use `{7}`. Below is the sample code which will use `/^059\d{7}$/g` regex.

```js
$('#check_btn').click(function() {
  var text = $('#input_1_4').val();
  regExp = /^059\d{7}$/g;
  var regexMatched = (text.match(regExp) != null) ? 'Matched' : 'Did not match';
 $('#result').text(regexMatched);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_1_4"/>
<button id="check_btn">
Check!!
</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```